# How to loop through an array using .each starting at an index in Ruby

Tags: ruby

Ok, so we all know that you can do the following:

```
array.each{ |value|
    puts value
}
```

What if, however, I want to start at element `n` instead of starting at the beginning; *i.e.* `n=0`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also do

`array.drop(n).each { |v| puts v }`

Comment: Is drop mutative; that is, if I call upon it again will the `0...n-1` entries still be there?

Comment: `drop` doesn't modify the original array

Answer (score 1):

You can call a subarray with a range like this:

```
array[n..-1].each { |value| puts value }
```

Where n is the index you'd like to start at, and -1 will always point to the last index of an array.

Comment: ...or insert `next if value < n`, which avoids the need to create the temporary array `array[n..-1]`. You could also write `puts array[n..-1]`.